# The other bow of Shiva - Ajagava

Tags: shiva, puranas, shiva-purana, weapon, pinaka

Lord Shiva had 2 bows - **Pinaka and Ajagava**.  There are few stories associated with the first bow **Pinaka** like Sita swayamvar.

Are there any distinct stories/incidents associated with **Ajagava** that have been mentioned in our scriptures for instance Shiva Puran or any other purans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Significance of Rudrakshas:*
>
> **Maha Deva was tired in tracking the tricky and invincible Demon
> Tripurasura, finally pulled out his ‘Ajagava’ dhanush and despatched
> the unique Vikaaraal arrow and killed him.** The long chase of the
> Asura who was fortified with Brahma’s boons tired out Maheswara and
> this tedious task ended up with profuse tears from his right eye
> signifying Surya Netra and from the streams thus materialised emerged
> Rudraksha Trees yielded twenty kinds of yellow seeds, while from his
> left eye called Soma Netra came sixteen varieties of white coloured
> beads and from the third eye on the forehead called Agni Netra came
> black beads.

> [Source - The book "PURANA SARAAMSHA (Quintessence of Puranas)"](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/psaaram/bookview.php?chapnum=12)

According to this book, the story of Lord Shiva killing Tripurasura using the Ajagava bow is found in Padma Purana, Devi Bhagavatam, Shiva Purana and Skanda Purana.

> (Source: Padma Purana, Devi Bhagavata, Siva Purana, Skanda Purana
> etc.)

According to Matsya Purana, Agajava was used again by Lord Shiva during the battle that ensued as a result of Chandra abducting Brihaspati's wife Tara.

Quoting from the book ["Essence of Matsya Purana"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/matsya/bookview.php?chapnum=7):

> In course of time, Chandra got infatuated with Devi Tara, the wife
> Deva Guru Brihaspati and took her away to his residence despite heavy
> protests of Deva Guru, Sadhyagana, Lokapalakas, Marudganas, and even
> Bhagavan Shiva himself. **Shiva felt highly offended and invoked the
> Ekadasha Rudras led by Vamadeva, pulled out his bow called
> ‘Ajagava**’, and accompanied by eighty four Ganas, Ganesha, Kubera
> with his shata koti Yakshas, Padma Vetala, three lakh Nagas and twelve
> lakh Kinnaras and so on. Chandra on his part too elisted the support
> of Nakshatras, Rakshasas, Asuras, Daityas, Shanishwara, Mangala, and
> so on.

However, according to the writings of [this blog](https://sreenivasaraos.com/2012/09/29/the-rudras-eleven/), Ajagava is nothing but the Pinaka bow (and I agree with this view).

> Rudra is described as fierce; armed with the mighty bow (pinaka), and
> a quiver holding unending array of arrows and missiles which are
> terrifyingly swift and penetrating. His fast-flying arrows, ‘brilliant
> shafts run about the heaven and the earth’ (RV 7.46.3).
>
> **Pinaka the powerful, sturdy bow with a wide span, bending along the course of the Sun , is said to be  the symbol of Rudra, the Isana
> (Lord); and,  his supremacy over all others. In the later texts,
> Pinaka is also known as Ajagava, the southern part of the Sun’s path.
> (Ajagava is also explained as a bow made of the horns of goats.)**
>
> Oh, the devoted to the devotees, always travelling in the chariot,
> ever young, fierce like the lion, vanquisher of the enemies, May the
> devotees pray to you. May you make us happy. May your armies fight
> against the enemies and be merciful towards us. There is none that
> matches him in strength. He is the Ishana the Master of the world; he
> is the father of worlds (Bhuvanasya pitaram).He commands men and
> entrusts tasks. He sets things in motion and makes flow like a river.
> He is medhavi, intelligent and the compassionate one. He is praised as
> midvah, for his generosity. As he is an auspicious one, he is called
> Shiva. (RV: 2-33-7; 6-49-10; 7-46-2)

Note: As [per Mahabharata](https://www.astrojyoti.com/mahabharata7-43.htm), the king Prithu (from whom the earth got it's name Prithivi) also used to own a bow called Ajagava.

> The very mountains used to yield him openings that he might pass
> through them. The standard of his car never broke (obstructed by
> anything). Once on a time, the tall trees of the forest, the
> mountains, the gods, the Asuras, men, the snakes, the seven Rishis,
> the Apsaras, and the Pitris, all came to Prithu, seated at his ease,
> and addressing him, said, ‘Thou art our Emperor. Thou art our king.
> Thou art our protector and Father.
>
> Thou art our Lord. Therefore, O great king, give us boons after our
> own hearts, through which we may, for ever, obtain gratification and
> joy.’ **Unto them Prithu, the son of Vena, said, So be it. Then taking
> up his Ajagava bow[117] and some terrible arrows the like of which
> existed not, he reflected for a moment.**

Answer (score 1):

There was a mention of Ājagava in [Viṣṇu Purāṇa | Book 1 - Chapter 13](http://scriptures.redzambala.com/vishnu-purana/vishnu-purana-book-1-chapter-13.html).

> Sages eliminated King Vena, who  reviled Yagna (the god of sacrifice)
> and thus was not fit to reign over the earth.
>
> As the kingdom is without a king, the dishonest men have begun to
> seize the property of their neighbours.
>
> The sages, hearing this, consulted, and together rubbed the the right
> arm of the king, who had left no offspring, to produce a son. From
> which friction was engendered the illustrious son of Veṇa, named
> Prithu, resplendent in person, as if the blazing deity of Fire bad
> been manifested.
>
> There then fell from the sky the primitive bow (of Mahādeva) named
> ***Ājagava***, and celestial arrows, and panoply from heaven.

---

The story continued, as follows:

> Protecting this earth, the monarch performed many great sacrificial
> ceremonies, accompanied by liberal donations.
>
> His subjects soon approached him, suffering from the famine by which
> they were afflicted, as all the edible plants had perished during the
> season of anarchy.
>
> In reply to his question of the cause of their coming, they told him,
> that in the interval in which the earth was without a king all
> vegetable products had been withheld, and that consequently the people
> had perished.
>
> "Thou," said they, "art the bestower of subsistence to us; thou art
> appointed, by the creator, the protector of the people: grant us
> vegetables, the support of the lives of thy subjects, who are
> perishing with hunger."
>
> On hearing this, Prithu took up his **divine bow Ājagava**, and his
> celestial arrows, and in great wrath marched forth to assail the
> Earth.
>
> Earth, assuming the figure of a cow, fled hastily from him, and
> traversed, through fear of the king, the regions of Brahmā and the
> heavenly spheres; but wherever went the supporter of living things,
> there she beheld Vaiṇya with uplifted weapons: